# How to run multiple firefox webdriver tests

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I try to run multiple webdriver tests each trying to use firefox, i am facing problems.

Following is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-23-96.us-west-2.compute.internal', ip: '172.31.23.96', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at feedbackWorksproperly.main(feedbackWorksproperly.java:23)


sudo javac -cp ".:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/selenium-java-2.41.0-srcs.jar:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/selenium-java-2.41.0.jar:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/libs/*" feedbackWorksproperly.java

sudo java -cp ".:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/selenium-java-2.41.0-srcs.jar:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/selenium-java-2.41.0.jar:/includes/selenium-2.41.0/libs/*" feedbackWorksproperly
```

Following is the way I initialize the webdriver

```
    String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
    final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path",
        "/usr/bin/firefox"));
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);
    FirefoxDriver wd;
    wd = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

Note I have a rest server which runs the tests upon the request. SO everytime it gets a request which comtains the java code, it will go ahead and run the test independent of other tests currently running on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get how exactly you "multiple webdriver tests"?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are running both drivers at the same time?
If this is the case,

`Unable to bind to locking port 7054`

looks like the other one is running on the same port. Using a different Port might work.

However I would recommend using Selenium Grid for running tests on different browsers/parallel
see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2